# regex for not allowing <> special characters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

HI All I am using regex for not allowing special characters

I want to allow \  / * ? % | : , ( ) - _ ; # . + characters only. Its working fine for all except <>.

Can any one help me with this. May be I am doing some mistake in my code.

Thanks
here is my code:

```
public validate(val: any) {
    let regExp = /^[ \\/*?%|()-_;#.+:, a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    //if (!val.match(regExp) || val.length < 1) 
    if (!regExp.test(val) || val.length < 1) 
      return false;
      else
      return true;

  }
```

Comment: `-` is special inside `[...]`, you need to escape it

Comment: @georg Unless it's at the end (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Yes, change `)-_` to `)\-_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the escaping of the `-` as mentioned in the comment by @georg on your question, it would be:

```js
let regExp = /^[ \\/*?%|()\-_;#.+:, a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

Apparently, you may need to also escape the `/` character inside:

```js
let regExp = /^[ \\\/*?%|()\-_;#.+:, a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

Comment: Why should he put `^` inside of the range?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Oh, yeah. I forgot what the `^` at the beginning does. I'll edit the post to fix that.